# Samsung Grand duos not visible in Mac Finder but visible in DDMS

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, macos

I have eclipse installed and can see my device DDMS tab. Debugging also works normal. But oddly, I dont see my device (both internal memory and sd card) in Finder. I am unable to transfer to-and-fro my Mac. My Android OS version is - 4.1.2 (Jellybeans)

Solutions already tried:

1) Rebooting both device and system multiple times.

2) Select/unselecting "USB Debugging" in developer options.

3) Connecting device as "Media Device(MTP)" and "Camera (PTP)"

4) Installing Kies and trying to access device from there. I get a perpetual "Connecting..." message.

[image]

5) Plugging/Unplugging device from Mac. I get the message "Try reconnecting or restarting your device."

[image]

The device is definitely getting detected by the system as its shown in DDMS. But what could be the possible cause of not letting me access the storage?

P.S.: Device works fine in Windows, both storage duly pops up in the "Computer" section.

Comment: permission problem? what group/id is DDMS under, maybe kies on mac os/x needs to be on the same group?

Comment: How and where do I check this?

Answer (score -1):

Disabling 'debugging mode' did the trick for me.